# get main window

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to get the main Window of an application written C#.
Application.MainWindow Property does not work :(

uses:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using My;
using MyDialogs;

using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Interop;
```

Comment: R u trying in WPF or Winforms? if it is winform check with this URL http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/99df9c07-c117-465a-9207-fa3534982021

Comment: It does not exist as a property, the Window object.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a line of code like this in your application anywhere?

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Where Form1 is the type of the form that is created when your application starts.  This is code created by default when you create a new Windows Forms application.  If you want to remember that instance, you just need to store the result in a variable accessible by other classes.  For example:

```
static class Program
{
  public static Form1 MainForm;

  // ...

  static void Main()
  {
     // ...
     MainForm = new Form1();
     Application.Run(MainForm);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have this private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   Application.EnableVisualStyles();
   Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
   Application.Run(new MainForm());
  }

Answer (score 1):

I think your application type is Windows Forms application. That follows from you post:

> I have this

```
private static void Main(string[] args) { 
    Application.EnableVisualStyles(); 
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
    Application.Run(new MainForm()); 
}
```

So, you can't use MainWindow object (type of  System.Windows.Window), because it's using in WPF. Create new WPF project, and you can acces Application.MainWindow property.